# ReactJS (Hook) pushing new value in array state causing existing state values being replaced instead

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, react-hook-form, yup

I have discovered a weird issue in my app, I used `react-hook-form` together with `yup` schema to validate my form. The goals is simple, to be able to add an item and render it back into a table, it should has be done technically by calling my `addRecord` function and passing the param into a state. **Here is the issue: the whole existing values in my state are replaced with the new value that I pushed into**. I suspect this issue was come from `yup`. However, since I rarely using `yup` so I was unfamiliar with this library and I don't know how it will cause this bug. I will provide my code below and I really hope for your guys assist.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { Container, Row, Col, Form, Button, Table } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import * as yup from "yup";
import Header from "../../components/Header";
import { takeIcon } from "../../helpers/iconMapper";

function IncomingCreate() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [dataList, setDataList] = useState([]);
  const schema = yup.object({
    purchaseQty: yup.string().required("Cannot be empty"),
    costPcs: yup.string().required("Cannot be empty"),
  });

  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm({ resolver: yupResolver(schema) });

  const addRecord = (data) => {
    console.log("ADDING RECORD ", data);
    setDataList((dataList) => [...dataList, data]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("ACTUAL", dataList);
  }, [dataList]);

  return (
    <Container fluid className="p-4">
      <Header className="d-flex align-items-center">
        <span
          className="cst-clickable cst-hover-color-respond me-2"
          onClick={() => navigate(-1)}
        >
          {takeIcon("backspace")}
        </span>
        <span>ORDER INPUT</span>
      </Header>
      <Row className="mx-0">
        <Col xs={12} md={4} className="cst-border-right">
          <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(addRecord)}>
            <Form.Group>
              <Form.Label>Item Price</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control {...register("costPcs")} />
            </Form.Group>

            <Row className="mx-0 d-flex justify-content-between">
              <Col xs={5} md={5} className="px-0">
                <Form.Group>
                  <Form.Label>Qty</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control {...register("purchaseQty")} />
                </Form.Group>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              variant="none"
              className="cst-btn-secondary w-100"
            >
              ADD
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </Col>
        <Col xs={12} md={8}>
          <Container>
            <h3>Adding List</h3>
            {dataList.length > 0 && (
              <>
                <Table responsive>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      {["Item Price", " Qty"].map((i) => (
                        <th key={i}>{i}</th>
                      ))}
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    {dataList.map((cell, idx) => (
                      <tr key={idx}>
                        <td>{cell.costPcs}</td>
                        <td>{cell.purchaseQty}</td>
                      </tr>
                    ))}
                  </tbody>
                </Table>
              </>
            )}
          </Container>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default IncomingCreate;
```

What did I tried:

1. replacing `setDataList((dataList) => [...dataList, data]);` with `setDataList([...dataList, data])`;
2. manually pushing state with `let arr = [...dataList]` and `dataList.push(arr)`
3. Calling other functin instead of `addRecord()`
4. using shape() in yup schema

What I expect:
Being able to push a new data into a state without replacing the whole state value, together with react-hook-form and yup validation implemented.

Demonstration for my issue:

```
const [arr, setArr] = useState(["1","2"]);
setArr(arr => [...arr,"3"])
// Result arr: ["3","3","3"]
```

Demonstration  for what I want:

```
const [arr, setArr] = useState(["1","2"]);
setArr(arr => [...arr,"3"])
// Result arr: ["1","2","3"]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "replacing the whole state value", in React you tend to always replace the whole state value (i.e. create a new reference). Btw I don't see a need to have your schema in the render function wastefully being re-created every render.

Comment: @Dominic if you have read my issue carefully, you will notice that I'm trying to pushing a new value into an existing state ( demonstration: [n1,n2,n3]+n4 ), but instead of being pushed, the new value is replacing the whole state ( demonstration: [n4,n4,n4,n4] ). Therefore, if my schema may cause bug in this scale of app, it means that library was not worthy at all?

Comment: What sort of data does `dataList` contain? It looks like each item in `dataList` could be referencing the same object. If so, you may want to try modifying `addRecord` to pluck out the data that you're interested in into a new object before adding to dataList.

Comment: @BenStephens it contains object, received from my form and was not referencing to a duplicate object. I have checked with console.log in addRecord to make sure each of object received from the form is correct before passed it to a state.